# .less files not getting picked up by less-loader

Tags: reactjs, less, create-react-app, less-loader, customize-cra

I have created a react app using create-react-app and I am using less for css. My app builds correctly, but none of the less files are loaded in build/static folder

I am using `customize-cra` with `react-app-rewired` to add a loader for less files.

config-overrides.js file

```
const {
    override,
    addLessLoader
} = require('customize-cra');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
    addLessLoader({
        paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')],
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        sourceMap: true,
    })
   
  );
```

scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --passWithNoTests",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "release": "CI=true react-app-rewired test --coverage && npm run build && npm run package && npm run posttest",
  },
```

dependencies

```
"less": "^4.1.1",
"less-loader": "^8.0.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.2",
"webpack": "4.44.2",
"customize-cra": "^1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error that I was getting was
`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js): TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`

Referred [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/81267234394/) post and lowered the version of less-loader to 5.0.0 and it started working